# vulnerability attack Code Evaluation (Apache Struts)

Tags: security

Recently I did some vulnerability scan and got some issue. One critical issue is Code Evaluation (Apache Struts) ie An attacker can execute arbitrary Apache Struts code on the system. The attacker may also be able to execute arbitrary system commands. It also gives some solution like Do not accept input from end users which will be directly interpreted as source code. If this is a business requirement, validate all input to the application by removing any data that could be directly interpreted as Apache Struts source
code.

Can anyone help me to resolve this type of issue as I am not able to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of these issues can be resolved by upgrading to the latest Apache struts version. Sadly for many legacy applications built with struts this will not always be possible or easy.

For "Do not accept input from end users which will be directly interpreted as source code"

This relates to "Struts OGNL language" and " REST Plugin"  vulnerabilities.

Here is a good [resource](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-45/product_id-6117/Apache-Struts.html) to read more about existing vulnerabilities like this, in particular look for  the links that contain  'Remote Code Execution' in the description.

Question "What to do when you cant upgrade."

You can start by escaping all inputs. Struts tags particularly for the new struts version do a good job of escaping html, but if you have jsp code like

`<input id="..." class="..." type="text" name="...." value="<%= some wide open ognl expression""%>"/>`

then this needs to be escaped. And the value in java returned from this input need to be sandboxed and quarantined to the max. Similarly for any rest data via rest plugin. Even then you are probably not safe so please take appropriate actions regards data access from processes spawned from your application(s).